Class AB amplifier with opamp
https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/probing_cores
While studying this circuit for driving inductive load, the author has wrote opamp cannot provide bipolar current,does he mean source and sink ability is not good,not able to interpret it properly,I have seen similar circuits which use supply lines of opamp to drive the classAB stage,but can't reason it,can someone explain it

This is what he mentioned about the technique



the author has wrote opamp cannot provide bipolar current

If I didn't get it wrong, what is meant by "bipolar" there is something like a differential output i.e. two independent outputs with the same amplitude but with opposite polarity (ignoring the common-mode or offset here).

ImgSrc
So yes, an ordinary op-amp doesn't have a "bipolar" output.


I have seen similar circuits which use supply lines of opamp to drive the classAB stage,but can't reason it,can someone explain it

A class-AB amp is basically a class-B (push/pull) amp but the transistors are biased to prevent/reduce crossover distortion.
With that old trick, it's possible to send differential (or inverted) signals to the driver transistors along with DC bias.
Normally, it's possible to bias the transistors externally and drive the output stage from the op-amp.


the author has wrote op-amp cannot provide bipolar current

An op-amp's output can certainly sink or source current and, in that respect it is bipolar. As to why he said it that is impossible for me to answer and there's no point speculating because it's wrong.

I have seen similar circuits which use supply lines of op-amp to drive
the class AB stage, but can't reason it, can someone explain it

What a lot of op-amps struggle to do is drive their outputs close to both power rails. So, using a power supply resistor sort of provides a solution to that. The current driven from or taken by the op-amp output (driving the 200 Ω load) is sufficient to produce a voltage across the 51 Ω resistor that can control the BJTs attached to it. This allows near enough full supply range control of the BJTs.
Please consider using a simulator and look at the voltages produced across each 51 Ω resistor and it should become clear.
However, op-amps are generally not happy without supply decoupling capacitors hence, don't expect this type of circuit to generally work on all op-amps.

So if you want extract the maximum out of class ab(i.e drive level upto supply -1.4 v drop for the transistor pair) but also have stability of opamp as a driving unit we can have a consideration for this circuit,but unless a feedback loop is there,stability of opamp does not play a major part here..am I getting it right?

@dhuwarkesh sorry but I'm not going to recommend using this type of design. If you want to extract the most out of a class AB you would bootstrap the driver stage and run the op-amps how they are meant to be run and not run the risk of instability (with or without feedback). I can only recommend that if you have an op-amp, you use it as specified in its data sheet. Of course, if the data sheet says it can be used like this then no problem.

Sorry I was not clear,I meant to say a single stage amplifier suffice here in place of opamp,but temperature and other drift need to compensated for both output stage and driving stage. when opamp is used first stage drive stability is good compared to single stage, but he should have compensated the output stage drift by feedback to the opamp which he has not done,some advantage available is not used,that's what I meant.

@dhuwarkesh I'm sorry but I don't know where you are going with this at all. If you have a new question (it sure seems like that) it should be asked in a new post. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
